# Is it possible to get exact angle of an image capture

Tags: android, camera, rotation, sensors, angle

I am developing an app where the user needs to capture the image **without tilting the camera** .  So if he tilts the camera i need to find the **angle** and send some toast message.  Here I could find the orientation, but i supposed to get the angle. Thanks..

```
 private void addSensorListener() {

        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

                float x = event.values[0];
                float y = event.values[1];
                if (x<5 && x>-5 && y > 5)
                    device_orientation = 0;
                else if (x<-5 && y<5 && y>-5)
                    device_orientation = 90;
                else if (x<5 && x>-5 && y<-5)
                    device_orientation = 180;
                else if (x>5 && y<5 && y>-5)
                    device_orientation = 270;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);


    }
```

Comment: Try finding the azimuth angle.
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/1av1la/simple_and_complete_android_device_rotation/

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I will try it